# Ruby getting into recursion

Tags: ruby, recursion

**So, can someone please explain how this solves the problem?**

*I don't understand how it is getting #array.sum, by calling itself
and just repeating #array[0] + `sum_array(array[1..-1])`. I'm aware it works itself down until the `array == 0` , and then work's itself back??*

**Can someone trace me threw the steps?**

Example:

```
# sum_array([])             # => 0
# sum_array([5])            # => 5
# sum_array([5, 2])         # => 7
# sum_array([4, 10, -1, 2]) # => 15

#??################################??#
def sum_array(array)
return 0 if array.empty?

array[0] + sum_array(array[1..-1])
end
#??###############################??#
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, `array[1..-1]` is the same as `array` except the first element has been removed from the array.

So `array[0] + sum_array(array[1..-1])` means "add the first element to the sum of every element other than first element".  If you think it about, that is equivalent to just adding up each element in the array.  (Addition is supposed to be [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), so it's valid to add up the last elements in the array first instead of starting by adding the first two elements.)

You could write it out as math equations like this:

> (a + b + c + d) = a + (b + c + d) = a + (b + (c + d))

You can trace through the steps *yourself* if you add some simple `puts` debugging commands like this:

```rb
def sum_array(array)
  return 0 if array.empty?
  puts "sum_array called with #{array.inspect}"
  tail = sum_array(array[1..-1])
  puts "sum_array returning #{array[0]} + #{tail}"
  array[0] + tail
end

sum_array([2, 4, 7, 8])
```

Answer (score 2):

@David's answer can be enhanced by separating the various instances of the method by indenting. Here all code that begins in the same column corresponds to the same instance of the method.

```
INDENT = 6
$col = -INDENT
def indent; $col += INDENT; end
def undent; $col -= INDENT; end
def pu(s); puts "#{" "*$col}#{s}"; end 
def puhline; pu('-'*(65-$col)); end
```

```
def sum_array(array)
  indent
  puhline
  pu "sum_array called with argument array = #{array.inspect}"
  if array.empty?
    pu "returning 0 as array is empty"
    puhline
    undent
  end
  return 0 if array.empty?
  pu "calling sum_array(#{array[1..-1].inspect})"
  tail = sum_array(array[1..-1])
  pu "sum_array returned tail = #{tail.inspect}"
  pu "returning array[0] + tail = #{array[0] + tail}"
  puhline
  undent
  array[0] + tail
end
```

```
sum_array([2, 4, 7, 8])
  #=> 21
```

The following is displayed.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
sum_array called with argument array = [2, 4, 7, 8]
calling sum_array([4, 7, 8])
      -----------------------------------------------------------
      sum_array called with argument array = [4, 7, 8]
      calling sum_array([7, 8])
            -----------------------------------------------------
            sum_array called with argument array = [7, 8]
            calling sum_array([8])
                  -----------------------------------------------
                  sum_array called with argument array = [8]
                  calling sum_array([])
                        -----------------------------------------
                        sum_array called with argument array = []
                        returning 0 as array is empty
                        -----------------------------------------
                  sum_array returned tail = 0
                  returning array[0] + tail = 8
                  -----------------------------------------------
            sum_array returned tail = 8
            returning array[0] + tail = 15
            -----------------------------------------------------
      sum_array returned tail = 15
      returning array[0] + tail = 19
      -----------------------------------------------------------
sum_array returned tail = 19
returning array[0] + tail = 21
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

To understand recursion, you must first understand recursion. Just kidding, kind of. I'll give a slightly different answer than those here.

Imagine that we expressed this in another language, say Scheme/Lisp...
Also imagine we have three functions:

- `(null? a)` which tells us if the array `a` is empty/null.
- `(car a)` which returns the first element of the array `a`.
- `(cdr a)` which returns the rest of the array/list.
- Oh and addition is weird too (+ 1 2) == 3

```lisp
; If `a` is empty, the sum is 0.
; Otherwise, the sum is the first item plus
; the result of calling sum on the rest of the list.
(define (sum a)
  (if (null? a)
    0
    (+ (car a) (sum (cdr a)))))
```

We can trace the call to `(sum '(1 2 3 4))`:

```lisp
(sum '(1 2 3 4))
(+ 1 (sum '(2 3 4)))
(+ 1 (+ 2 (sum '(3 4))))
(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (sum '(4)))))
(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ 4 (sum '())))))
(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 (+ 4 0))))
(+ 1 (+ 2 (+ 3 4)))
(+ 1 (+ 2 7))
(+ 1 9)
(10)
```

Comment: The last code block nicely illustrates how this recursion breaks down the sum operation into a sequence of binary operations (addition) and evaluates those to retrieve the sum. In Ruby you could write `(sum([1, 2, 3, 4]))` → `(1 + (sum([2, 3, 4])))` → `(1 + (2 + (sum([3, 4]))))` etc.

Comment: i'm a big fan of the Lisp family of languages but not sure why it's being used to answer a ruby question

Comment: I used scheme for a few reasons: (1) the question was more about understanding the _shape_ of recursive processes than it was about ruby, (2) to not get bogged down by notation, and (3) I think scheme's minimal notation lends itself to easier-to-follow traces.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is easiest to understand in the way you would understand any recursive definitions in mathematics (think about the famous Fibonacci sequence, as example), or mathematical proofs by induction.

In those you establish a base case, and then have a formula which reduces a more complicated case to a simpler case.

For instance, in the Fibonacci case, you would write in mathematics something like:

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
n>1 : fib n = fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

In your sum example, you would have likewise

```
sum [] = 0
sum [x:xs] = x + sum xs
```

You code is virtually a direct translation of these mathematical formulas into Ruby.

Having said this, your function would be more idiomatically expressed by

```
def sum_array(array)
  array.reduce(&:+)
end
```

This is because your recursion pattern is so commonplace, that the Ruby class `Enumerable` (which Array is a subclass of) contains a generic `reduce` method for such a case. Have a look at the Ruby docs to see, what else you can do with `reduce`.

Comment: Actually, it would more idiomatically be expressed by `array.sum`, which performs some neat tricks to increase accuracy when the array elements are `Float`s.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : Which Ruby version introduced `Array#sum`? I'm for technical reason still on the pretty old 1.9.3, and this knows only `String#sum`, which does something completely different. The advantage of `reduce` is that you can use it with different accessors, and also define the base case, so it is close to the mathematical model which I described.

Comment: `Enumerable#sum` and `Array#sum` were introduced in Ruby 2.4. I think the optimizations have been in there from day 1. There is an additional optimization in `Enumerable#sum` for `Range`s, where it uses the closed-form formula to compute the sum in O(1) time. (Which I find super-annoying because it teaches bad OO: instead of special-casing `Range`s in `Enumerable#sum`, it should just be overridden as `Range#sum`, but I digress.)

Answer (score 1):

We can gain deeper understanding and appreciation for recursive algorithms by applying [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

1. If the input `a` is empty, return the empty sum, `0`
2. (inductive) `a` has **at least one element**. Add the first element `a[0]` to the result of the recursive sub-problem `sum a[1..]` and return

```rb
def sum a
  if a == [] then
    0                    # 1
  else
    a[0] + (sum a[1..])  # 2
  end
end
```

```rb
puts (sum [1,2,3])
```

```rb
6
```

Recursion is a functional heritage and in functional style we can replace any expression with its return value. This is known as [referential transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency). Using this property we can see how `sum` behaves -

```rb
sum [1,2,3]
== [1,2,3][0] + (sum [1,2,3][1..])
== 1 + (sum [2,3])
== 1 + [2,3][0] + (sum [2,3][1..])
== 1 + 2 + (sum [3])
== 1 + 2 + [3][0] (sum [3][1..])
== 1 + 2 + 3 (sum [])
== 1 + 2 + 3 + 0
== 1 + 2 + 3
== 1 + 5
== 6
```

Or we could write `psum` that draws the visualization for us. The same inductive reasoning can be applied -

```rb
def psum a
  if a == [] then
    "0"                           # 1
  else
    "(#{a[0]} + #{psum a[1..]})"  # 2
  end
end
```

```rb
puts (psum [1,2,3])
```

```rb
(1 + (2 + (3 + 0)))
```

Comment: `sum` and `psum` here are only used to develop understanding of recursive procedures. as Jorg mentions `Array#sum` and `Enumerable#sum` have optimizations and should be used in real world programs.